# Two event on one button click Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

First I have loop in pl/sql example (EX 1)

```
begin
  declare
  l_string varchar2(4000);
  begin
       :P15_URL_PARAMETER := '';

       FOR i IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP  
           l_string := l_string || APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i) || '-';
       END LOOP;  

       :P15_URL_PARAMETER := l_string;   
  end;
end;
```

After P15_URL_PARAMETER field get value from above plsql I need call
redirect to url example (EX 2)

```
javascript:var a = window.open('f?p=800:105:&APP_SESSION.:.....xyz........&P15_URL_PARAMETER.');
```

In this moment, first on BUTTON_1 I call process (EX 1) and then P15_URL_PARAMETER get value on second button BUTTON_2 call redirect to url (EX 2).  All work fine, but is it possible (EX 1 and EX 2) call on one button click?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

I guess so. That would be done by creating a **dynamic action** with two *true actions*:

- one is "Execute PL/SQL Code" (which is the first piece of code you posted)
- another one is "Execute JavaScript Code" (which is the second code you posted)

Comment: Hi, not working, field P15_URL_PARAMETER is empty.  Redirect to url must wait while  P15_URL_PARAMETER get value from plsql.  I don't know is it possible create sleep between dynamic action?

Comment: Aha. Two things cross my mind. First is to change "Execute PL/SQL Code" to "Set value". Another is to leave it *as currently is*, but add another action: Submit (as the 2nd action), as it'll put items' values into session state.